# File manipulation in Perl

Tags: perl, csv, text

I have a simple .csv file that has that I want to extract data out of a write to a new file.

I to write a script that reads in a file, reads each line, then splits and structures the columns in a different order, and if the line in the .csv contains 'xxx' - dont output the line to output file.

I have already managed to read in a file, and create a secondary file, however am new to Perl and still trying to work out the commands, the following is a test script I wrote to get to grips with Perl and was wondering if I could aulter this to to what I need?-

```
open (FILE, "c1.csv") || die "couldn't open the file!";
open (F1, ">c2.csv") || die "couldn't open the file!";

#print "start\n";

sub trim($);

sub trim($)
{
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}

$a = 0;
$b = 0;
while ($line=<FILE>)
{
    chop($line);

    if ($line =~ /xxx/)
    {
        $addr = $line;
        $post = substr($line, length($line)-18,8);
    }
    $a = $a + 1;
}

print $b;
print " end\n";
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I thought I'd give you a couple of style pointers, I hope you don't mind. 0.  PUt `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of all of your scripts.  You will have to declare variables with `my`, but it will save you debugging time in the long run--example `my $foo = bar();`  1. In perl there is no need to predeclare your subroutines--in over a decade of heavy Perl use, I have *never* needed this feature.  2. In general, don't use prototypes on your subs, they don't work like they do in other languages. They are only compiler hints and can be bypassed easily.

Comment: More style pointers.  3. The variables `$a` and `$b` are special variables used by `sort`.  It's best not to use them anywhere else.  It can be safe if you make sure they are lexically scoped, but, in general, I avoid them.  4. Filehandles like `FILE` are global variables, and are best replaced with lexical handles.  5. Open has a 3 argument form and a 2 argument form.  The 2 argument version is kept for backwards compatibility, but it has some problems.  Use the 3 arg form instead.  Example of a modern 3-arg, lexical open:  `open my $fh, '>', $path_to_some_file or die "Didn't work: $!\n";`.

Comment: Most of these issues with your code are issues of outdated or confusing docs.  Fortunately, there are sources of more current Perl usage available.  brian d foy's **Effective Perl Programming** and chromatic's **Modern Perl** are a couple of excellent books.  Modern Perl is even available as a free download:  http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To manipulate CSV files it is better to use one of the available modules at CPAN. I like [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV):

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, empty_is_undef => 1 }) or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

open my $fh, "<", 'c1.csv' or die "ERROR: $!";
$csv->column_names('field1', 'field2');
while ( my $l = $csv->getline_hr($fh)) {
    next if ($l->{'field1'} =~ /xxx/);
    printf "Field1: %s Field2: %s\n", $l->{'field1'}, $l->{'field2'}
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but it brings up the error "Can't locate Text/CSV.pm in @INC <@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/Lib .>

Comment: I agree completely with PacoRG; Text::CSV is the right way to go here.

Comment: Lambo: you need to install the `Text::CSV` module first. Try installing it from PPM by following the instructions here: http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html

Comment: ah I see I was missing that! Thanks for that ill get it installed.

Comment: If Text::CSV isn't installed on your system and you don't have time to install it, then an alternative would be to use the Text::ParseWords module which is shipped as part of the standard Perl installation and will therefore already be installed.

Comment: @Lambo, Text::CSV and Text::CSV_XS are the standard CSV parsing modules in the Perl community.  Even if you choose to minimize your use of CPAN, these modules are definitely worth having in your toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

If you need do this only *once*, so don't need the program later you can do it with oneliner:

```
perl -F, -lane 'next if /xxx/; @n=map { s/(^\s*|\s*$)//g;$_ } @F; print join(",", (map{$n[$_]} qw(2 0 1)));'
```

Breakdown:

```
perl -F, -lane
     ^^^   ^ <- split lines at ',' and store fields into array @F

next if /xxx/;    #skip lines what contain xxx

@n=map { s/(^\s*|\s*$)//g;$_ } @F;
    #trim spaces from the beginning and end of each field
    #and store the result into new array @n

print join(",", (map{$n[$_]} qw(2 0 1)));
    #recombine array @n into new order - here 2 0 1
    #join them with comma
    #print
```

Of course, for the repeated use, or in a bigger project you should use some CPAN module. And the above oneliner has much cavetas too.